# Unable to change a function's paramaters, even though they exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this neat little project that monitors IMAP emails and can output them to a dictionary, text, or other file type stored on your PC.

However, it's not working correctly.

Here is the project:  [Email_Listener](https://github.com/njdreikosen/email_listener)

The problem I'm getting is that function parameters are not being passed to the script.

For example.  According to the text found in "email_processing.py". One should be able to create a file and change the default output.
Default output:

```
el.listen(timeout)
```

Different output:

```
el.listen(timeout,process_function=write_json_file)
```

This throws an error saying the name "write_json_file" is not defined.

I've imported the file "email_processing" and keyboard hints started to work.  I was able to write:

```
el.listen(timeout, email_processing.write_json_file())
```

And then got an error saying I was missing two keyword arguments for write_json_file().

I'm still pretty novice at python.  I was able to get the desired json output by editing the __init__.py.  I imported the json function from email_processing.py and then changed the default output method in the functions.

Why was I not able to get the code to work as the programmer who wrote it intended?

Comment: `el.listen(timeout, process_function=email_processing.write_json_file)`

Answer (score 1):

```
el.listen(timeout, email_processing.write_json_file())
```

That didn't work because of the `()` after the function name, which means that you're calling the function **now**.  And that function apparently requires two arguments, so it failed.

You're supposed to *pass* a function object without actually *calling* it.  `el.listen()` will call the function later when it needs to.

```
el.listen(timeout, process_function=email_processing.write_json_file)
```

Comment: That's it.  Just tested.  So in the docs the programmer wrote an example as: el.listen(timeout, process_function=write_json_file).  what would need to be done to the program to make this syntax correct?

Comment: @Texas_Technician I don't understand your question.  `el.listen(timeout, process_function=write_json_file)` is the correct syntax.  What do you mean "make the syntax correct"?  That example is _already_ correct...

Comment: if you write it as el.listen(timeout, process_function=write_json_file) an error will occur.  This is how the programmer wrote their example.  The way to get the desired result is to write el.listen(timeout, process_function=email_listener.write_json_file).  Really I'm just currious if the writer made a typo in the example or if they wrote the example as it was supposed to work, and there is a problem in the code.

Comment: I think you're taking their example much too literally.  `process_function=foo` just means "You're supposed to specify the name of a function here.  The function may be named whatever you like; we're using `foo` as an example".  The example does NOT mean "the function must be named exactly `write_json_file`".

Comment: Well, the actual example reads write_txt_file.  I wanted the write_json_file one.  I get what you're saying in that I may be taking it too literally.  But if the author intended for the function to be called by ...process_function=email_processing.write_txt_file).  Then why write ...process_function=write_txt_file?

Comment: @Texas_Technician Because there is no meaningful difference between `process_function=foo` and `process_function=foo.bar`.  Both of those things are just "the name of the function".  It would be utterly silly for documentation to care about such a small detail.

Comment: Except that process=foo causes an error.  Whereas process=foo.bar does not.

Comment: @Texas_Technician That's because _there is no function_ named `foo`, but _there is one_ named `foo.bar`.